# the area of the image under a specific holomorphic function of the unit disk

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(z)=z^3+\frac{z^2}{2}$. Let $D$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. How to compute
$$
Area(f(D))?
$$

In the case that $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ is injective,
\begin{align*}
Area(f(D))&=
\int_D |f'(z)|^2 ~ dx\,dy \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r\left|f'(re^{i\theta})\right|^2 ~ d\theta \, dr \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r \left(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty nc_nr^{n-1} e^{i(n-1)\theta}\right)\left(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n\overline{c_n}r^{n-1} e^{-i(n-1)\theta}\right)  ~ d\theta \, dr \\
&= \int_0^1\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\pi n^2|c_n|^2 r^{2n-1} \right)~dr \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\pi n^2}{2n} |c_n|^2 \\
&= \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty n|c_n|^2.
\end{align*}
But now $f$ is not injective. How to compute? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps find a subset $E$ of $D$ on which $f$ is injective such that $f(E)=f(D)$, and calculate the integral over $E$?

Comment: Dear Professor, I do not know how to solve... Could you give a help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Green's formula for the area: 
$$A= \frac12 \int (y\,dx-x\,dy) \tag1$$
where the integral is taken over the boundary. 
Here the boundary is parametrized by $x=\cos 3t+\frac12 \cos 2t$ and $y=\sin 3t+\frac12 \sin 2t$. The integrand in (1) should simplify nicely. The only unpleasant part is finding the interval of integration: since the curve self-intersects, it is not $[-\pi,\pi]$.

[image: curve]

Integrate over the outmost part of this curve. The domain of integration is  $[-\theta,\theta]$ where $\theta$ is the smallest positive root of $\sin 3t+\frac12 \sin 2t=0$. It can be found analytically with Wolfram Alpha, and presumably by hand too.