# How to compute the area of the given region (NBHM $2022$)?

Tags: complex-analysis, area, complex-integration

This is a question from NBHM $2022$ exam. It asks to find the area of the region $\{z+\frac{z^2}{2} \mid z\in \mathbb{C},|z| \leq 1\}$

Now $z+\frac{z^2}{2}$ = $\frac{(z+1)^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$.

The $-\frac{1}{2}$ part is just a translation, so it does not change the area. But I couldn't understand what is happening in the $\frac{(z+1)^2}{2}$ part. The resulting region is not a circular shape as the images of $i,-1,-i$ are $i,0,-i$ which lies on the same line. My question is how to understand what's happening in the $\frac{(z+1)^2}{2}$ part.
Edit: the answer is given $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: Hint: adapt [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/828903) strategy, but be careful with signs.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1764827/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a way to evaluate the area using complex coordinates $z = x+iy$ and $\bar{z} = x-iy$. The key is in terms of $z, \bar{z}$, the area element has the form:

$$dx \wedge dy = \frac{1}{2i} d\bar{z} \wedge dz$$

Let $\omega(z) = z + \frac{z^2}{2}$ and $D$ be the unit disk
and $C = \partial D$ be the unit circle.

Notice the map $C \in z \mapsto z + \frac{z^2}{2} \in \partial \omega(D)$ is 1-1, the area of $\omega(D)$ equals to

$$\begin{align}
\verb/Area/ &= \overbrace{\frac1{2i}\int_{\omega(D)}d\bar{\omega} \wedge d\omega
= \frac1{2i}\int_{\partial \omega(D)}\bar{\omega} d\omega}
^{\text{complex version of Stokes' theorem}}\\
&= \frac1{2i}\int_C \left(\bar{z} + \frac{\bar{z}^2}{2}\right)(1 + z)dz\end{align}
$$
Since $\bar{z} = \frac1z$ on $C$, we have

$$\begin{align}\verb/Area/ 
&=\frac1{2i}\int_C\left(\frac1z + \frac{2}{z^2}\right)(1+z)dz\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{2i} \verb/Res/_{z=0}\left[1 + \frac3{2z} + \frac1{2z^2}\right]\\
&= \frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the disk $\{z + 1 : \lvert z \rvert \le 1\}$ can be reparameterized as
$$
\{ r e^{it} : -\tfrac{\pi}{2} < t < \tfrac{\pi}{2}, 0 \le r \le 2 \cos t\},
$$
so its image under the map $z \mapsto z^2$ is
$$
\{ r e^{it} : -\pi < t < \pi, 0 \le r \le 4 (\cos \tfrac{t}{2})^2\},
$$
whose area follows from polar integration.

Answer (score 3):

$\textrm{Area Theorem}$:Let $f:\mathbb{D}\to f(\mathbb{D})$ is a conformal map with $f(0) =0$ and $f'(0) >0$ so that $f$ has a Taylor expansion $$f(z) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nz^n$$ $|z|<1
$ and $a_1>0$.

Then $$\textrm{Area}(f(\mathbb{D}))=\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|a_n|^2$$

---

Given $f(z) =z+\frac{z^2}{2}=\sum_{n\ge 0}{a_nz^n}$

$\begin{align}\textrm{Area}(f(\mathbb{D}))&=\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|a_n|^2\\&=\pi(1+\frac{1}{2})\\&=\frac{3\pi}{2}\end{align}$

Comment: Can you give any link about this theorem? i couldn't find anything upon searching.

Comment: The proof of the above theorem  follows from the @achille hui's proof combining with cauchy product of power series.

Comment: It can also be seen as an application of Parseval's identity (compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1764827/42969). The conditions $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) > 0$ are not really needed, only that $f$ is injective.